# Numpy array converts into C_CONTIGUOUS after trimming rows

Tags: numpy, catboost

Output of this is:

```
print(arr.shape)
print(arr.flags)
```

Output:

```
  (676, 3516)
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : False
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

But when I trim the rows using:

arr = arr[preds<0]

I get this output

```
(670, 3516)
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Now, when I use catboost to predict on the trimmed version of array, it takes 2x the time to predict compared to the original array. Catboost needs F_CONTIGUOUS array only I guess, not sure what contiguous array means.

How can I make the trimmed version F_CONTIGUOUS?

Comment: The initial array looks a lot like a transpose of some other array (expect the `writable` flag).  In any case it's a `view`, without its `owndata`.  But advanced indexing like that creates a copy, an array with its `owndata`.  I'm not aware of a way of doing that indexing without producing a default `C-contiguous` result.  If the original is indeed a transpose, you might want to first trim, and transpose.  There are also functions like `np.asfortranarray`, but I haven't used them enough to say whether it preserves value order as you want.

Comment: Ohh, I see. @hpaulj I created 1st arr using arr = df.values (from pandas dataframe)

Comment: Ok I vaguely remember looking at the flags for a frame.  A frame composed of columns/Series makes sense as F contiguous.